# ms sql server 2012 - deducing active rows for a time in the past using effective from and effective to dates

Tags: sql, timestamp

I have a table containing rows of pricing.

Each row has 3 timestamps, insert_date, effective_from and effective_to. (example row below)

I have a query that will show me instances where rows where the price has been wrongly entered as zero.

What I'd like to be able to do, is know what the price field was BEFORE the last update (I didn't want these to be updated to zero)

The query I have now is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   company..database_pricing_fixed 
WHERE  price = 0 
       AND status = 1 
ORDER  BY insert_date DESC
```

the table structure looks like this:

```
POSTCODE_KEY    EXP_ID  POSTCODE    SOURCE_POSTCODE_DISTRICT    DEST_POSTCODE_DISTRICT  PRICE   INSERT_DATE           EFFECTIVE_FROM    EFFECTIVE_TO    ACCOUNT_ID  STATUS    
W11_TW6 3XA       75    TW6 3XA          W11                          NULL                0       24/12/2013 01:32       24/12/2013 01:31   24/12/2013 03:41          32523 1
```

Comment: Price field before based on what? Same postcode, second nearest insert_date?

Comment: Yes, the postcode_key is essentially a product code or description of an item for sale. The price that appeared before the latest insert_date is exactly what I'm after

Answer (score 0):

With SQL Server 2012, you can use `LEAD()` to get the second closest price if the latest one inserted is 0;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT POSTCODE_KEY, EXP_ID, POSTCODE, SOURCE_POSTCODE_DISTRICT,
  DEST_POSTCODE_DISTRICT, 
    CASE WHEN PRICE = 0 
         THEN LEAD(PRICE) OVER (PARTITION BY POSTCODE_KEY 
                                ORDER BY INSERT_DATE DESC) 
         ELSE PRICE 
    END PRICE,   
    INSERT_DATE, EFFECTIVE_FROM, EFFECTIVE_TO, ACCOUNT_ID,STATUS, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY POSTCODE_KEY ORDER BY INSERT_DATE DESC) rn
  FROM DATABASE_pricing_fixed
)
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rn=1
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/13f9e/1).

Comment: I tried running this and got    Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 5
'LEAD' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near 'PRICE'.

Comment: Am using MS sql server management tools - 2012 edition. Am I doing something wrong? (I changed the FROM table to the full path)

Comment: @finngeraghty Since the management tools can be used as a separate download, are you sure you're using SQL Server 2012 and not just those management tools?

Comment: Oh dear, thanks for the heads up. Just checked; the DB itself is a MSSQL 2008. Is there another way to acheive what I need to for the 2008 edition?

Comment: Or, should I download the data I need, and try an insert it into a 2012 versioned local installation, then do the query on that database?

Answer (score 0):

I modified the DDL in Joachim's SQL Fiddle a bit and utilized this structure to find a SQL Server 2008 solution.

A_PRICE and B_PRICE are the original PRICE columns in each table of the LEFT JOIN. CALCULATED_PRICE is the price you want to use and is the result of determining if table A.PRICE is 0 and falling back to B.PRICE if it is. It furthermore falls back to 0 if a.PRICE is 0 and there is no preceding insert to reference. You can get rid of A_PRICE and B_PRICE.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f830a/3)

SEQ_A and SEQ_B are debugging values I used in my coding to help visualize the dataset. You can get rid of those.

Using this DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE DATABASE_pricing_fixed
    ([POSTCODE_KEY] varchar(11), [EXP_ID] int, [POSTCODE] varchar(7), [SOURCE_POSTCODE_DISTRICT] varchar(3), [DEST_POSTCODE_DISTRICT] varchar(4), [PRICE] int, [INSERT_DATE] varchar(16), [EFFECTIVE_FROM] varchar(16), [EFFECTIVE_TO] varchar(16), [ACCOUNT_ID] int, [STATUS] int)
;

INSERT INTO DATABASE_pricing_fixed
    ([POSTCODE_KEY], [EXP_ID], [POSTCODE], [SOURCE_POSTCODE_DISTRICT], [DEST_POSTCODE_DISTRICT], [PRICE], [INSERT_DATE], [EFFECTIVE_FROM], [EFFECTIVE_TO], [ACCOUNT_ID], [STATUS])
VALUES
    ('W11_TW6 3XA', 75, 'TW6 3XA', 'W11', NULL, 0, '24/12/2013 01:34', '24/12/2013 01:31', '24/12/2013 03:41', 32523, 1)
;
INSERT INTO DATABASE_pricing_fixed
    ([POSTCODE_KEY], [EXP_ID], [POSTCODE], [SOURCE_POSTCODE_DISTRICT], [DEST_POSTCODE_DISTRICT], [PRICE], [INSERT_DATE], [EFFECTIVE_FROM], [EFFECTIVE_TO], [ACCOUNT_ID], [STATUS])
VALUES
    ('W11_TW6 3XB', 75, 'TW6 3XA', 'W11', NULL, 47, '22/12/2013 01:32', '24/12/2013 01:31', '24/12/2013 03:41', 32523, 1)
;
INSERT INTO DATABASE_pricing_fixed
    ([POSTCODE_KEY], [EXP_ID], [POSTCODE], [SOURCE_POSTCODE_DISTRICT], [DEST_POSTCODE_DISTRICT], [PRICE], [INSERT_DATE], [EFFECTIVE_FROM], [EFFECTIVE_TO], [ACCOUNT_ID], [STATUS])
VALUES
    ('W11_TW6 3XC', 75, 'TW6 3XA', 'W11', NULL, 33, '24/12/2013 01:32', '24/12/2013 01:31', '24/12/2013 03:41', 32523, 1)
;
```

Solution:

```
WITH d1 AS (
  SELECT 
     *
    ,Seq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY POSTCODE ORDER BY INSERT_DATE)
  FROM DATABASE_pricing_fixed
)

SELECT a.POSTCODE_KEY
      ,a.EXP_ID
      ,a.POSTCODE
      ,a.SOURCE_POSTCODE_DISTRICT
      ,a.DEST_POSTCODE_DISTRICT
      ,A_PRICE = a.PRICE
      ,B_PRICE = b.PRICE
      ,CALCULATED_PRICE = COALESCE(NULLIF(a.PRICE, 0), b.PRICE, 0)
      ,a.INSERT_DATE
      ,a.EFFECTIVE_FROM
      ,a.EFFECTIVE_TO
      ,a.ACCOUNT_ID
      ,a.STATUS
      ,A_SEQ = a.Seq
      ,B_SEQ = b.Seq
FROM d1 a
LEFT JOIN d1 b
  ON  a.PRICE = 0 
  AND b.POSTCODE = a.POSTCODE
  AND a.Seq - b.Seq = 1
```